# How to tell which Card or SelectField is being changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have a list of Material UI Cards with a Select list inside each card.

```
  const ads = this.props.ads;
  let adsItems = ads.map((c, i) =>
     <div key={ads[i].adid}>
      <Card>
        <CardHeade>
          <SelectField
            id={String(ads[i].adid)}
            value={ads[i].status}
            onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <MenuItem key={1} value={`Idle`} primaryText={`Idle`} />
              <MenuItem key={2} value={`Sent`} primaryText {`Sent`} />
          </SelectField>
        </CardHeader>
      </Card>
     </div>
  );
```

Now when selecting a `MenuItem` I want to know which `Card` or `selectField` was changed. If I could simply pass the `SelectField` id in into the `onChange={this.handleChange}` in this case the id is `ads[i].adid` this would be solved simply.

I took a look at the Material UI docs and even their examples show when you select one `MenuItem` all the SelectFields get updated with the same value.

Is there any way I can know which `Card` or `SelectField` is being changed, that would help me greatly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply pass the id to change event like you said.

```
onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, ads[i].adid)}
```

if you do like below it won't work because you would be executing it rather than passing it as a prop.

```
// THIS WON'T WORK
onChange={this.handleChange(ads[i].adid)}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you very much, simple and clear explanation.